# How to align nav bar to bottom of window with no gap between buttons and window edge

Tags: html, css, web, alignment

I am trying to align nav bar images to the bottom of the window but i cant seem  to close the 5 px gap between the images and the bottom of the window.

How do I make the nav hug the bottom of the window without having this 5 px gap?

CSS:

```
#nav
{
position: absolute;
    bottom: 0%;
left: 26.5%;
    width: 50%;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id=nav>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Images are inline elements by default, so they inherit whatever your `line-height` for the parent. My preference for trumping this is to use either `img { display: inline-block; }` or `img { display: block; }`, depending on which makes more sense in the scenario.

Comment: this works but the problem is that then this affects the rest of the images on the page. can you isolate it just to affect a certain div?

Comment: or make it so that the images are not stacked?

Answer (score 0):

Images have line height because they're displayed inline by default and therefore allow space for character descenders. Deal with that and you're golden:

```
img {
    display: inline-block;
    line-height: <whatever your image height is>;
}
```

Comment: this set it to the bottom but created overflow so scrolling was enabled which i dont want